# finding the biggest subpalindrome in a string

Tags: java

I'm trying to find a subpalindrome in Java. But the below code doesn't provide the correct output.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    in.useDelimiter("\n");
    String text = in.next();
    int start = 0;
    int end = 0;

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while(i <= text.length())
    {
        j = i+1;
        while(j < text.length())
        {
            if(text.substring(i, j).equals(reverse(text.substring(i, j))))
            {
                if(j-i > end-start)
                {
                    start = i; end = j;
                }   
            }
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println(start + " : " + end);
}
static String reverse(String s)
{
    return new StringBuffer(s).reverse().toString();
}
```

Sample Output:

```
apros tda adda
7 : 12
after the ostso
11 : 14
att feref
5 : 8
```

All of the above are wrong.

PS: I'm aware that this is not an efficient algorithm.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding an error when looking at this; can you post another sample output?

Comment: Be sure to put the curly braces around the if(j-i > end-start) block or else only start = i; will be set.

Comment: @mprivat: I think that may be his issue.  Is that the entire problem?

Comment: I'm actually wondering why it doesn't crash...

Comment: http://johanjeuring.blogspot.com/2007/08/finding-palindromes.html

Comment: What @mprivat said. this also means that end=j is called every iteration of the inner loop.

Comment: i wrote python code for few days... and got carried away by that syntax

Comment: i corrected the code but still it fails. Added more test cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    in.useDelimiter("\n");
    String text = in.next();

    int start = 0;
    int end = 0;

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while(i < text.length())
    {
        j = i;
        while(j <= text.length())
        {
            if(text.substring(i, j).equals(reverse(text.substring(i, j))))
            {
                if(j-i > 1 && j-i > end-start)
                {
                    start = i; 
                    end = j;
                }   
            }
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println(start + " : " + (end-1));
}
static String reverse(String s)
{
    return new StringBuffer(s).reverse().toString();
}
```

Here is a more optimized version. This is based on [this](http://explored.tk/experiments/palindrome/#%5B%5B%22hello%20world%22,%5B%22p%22,0%5D,%5B%22p%22,0.5%5D,%5B%22c%22,0,1,0%5D,%5B%22p%22,1%5D,%5B%22c%22,0,2,0%5D,%5B%22p%22,1.5%5D,%5B%22c%22,1,2,0%5D,%5B%22p%22,2%5D,%5B%22c%22,1,3,0%5D,%5B%22p%22,2.5%5D,%5B%22c%22,2,3,1%5D,%5B%22c%22,1,4,0%5D,%5B%22p%22,3%5D,%5B%22c%22,2,4,0%5D,%5B%22p%22,3.5%5D,%5B%22c%22,3,4,0%5D,%5B%22p%22,4%5D,%5B%22c%22,3,5,0%5D,%5B%22p%22,4.5%5D,%5B%22c%22,4,5,0%5D,%5B%22p%22,5%5D,%5B%22c%22,4,6,0%5D,%5B%22p%22,5.5%5D,%5B%22c%22,5,6,0%5D,%5B%22p%22,6%5D,%5B%22c%22,5,7,0%5D,%5B%22p%22,6.5%5D,%5B%22c%22,6,7,0%5D,%5B%22p%22,7%5D,%5B%22c%22,6,8,0%5D,%5B%22p%22,7.5%5D,%5B%22c%22,7,8,0%5D,%5B%22p%22,8%5D,%5B%22c%22,7,9,0%5D,%5B%22p%22,8.5%5D,%5B%22c%22,8,9,0%5D,%5B%22p%22,9%5D,%5B%22c%22,8,10,0%5D,%5B%22p%22,9.5%5D,%5B%22c%22,9,10,0%5D%5D,%5B%22hello%20world%22,%5B%22p%22,0%5D,%5B%22c%22,0,0,1%5D,%5B%22p%22,0.5%5D,%5B%22c%22,0,1,0%5D,%5B%22p%22,1%5D,%5B%22c%22,1,1,1%5D,%5B%22c%22,0,2,0%5D,%5B%22p%22,1.5%5D,%5B%22c%22,1,2,0%5D,%5B%22p%22,2%5D,%5B%22c%22,2,2,1%5D,%5B%22c%22,1,3,0%5D,%5B%22p%22,2.5%5D,%5B%22c%22,2,3,1%5D,%5B%22c%22,1,4,0%5D,%5B%22p%22,3%5D,%5B%22c%22,3,3,1%5D,%5B%22c%22,2,4,0%5D,%5B%22p%22,3.5%5D,%5B%22c%22,3,4,0%5D,%5B%22p%22,4%5D,%5B%22c%22,4,4,1%5D,%5B%22c%22,3,5,0%5D,%5B%22p%22,4.5%5D,%5B%22c%22,4,5,0%5D,%5B%22p%22,5%5D,%5B%22c%22,5,5,1%5D,%5B%22c%22,4,6,0%5D,%5B%22p%22,5.5%5D,%5B%22c%22,5,6,0%5D,%5B%22p%22,6%5D,%5B%22c%22,6,6,1%5D,%5B%22c%22,5,7,0%5D,%5B%22p%22,6.5%5D,%5B%22c%22,6,7,0%5D,%5B%22p%22,7%5D,%5B%22c%22,7,7,1%5D,%5B%22c%22,6,8,0%5D,%5B%22p%22,7.5%5D,%5B%22c%22,7,8,0%5D,%5B%22p%22,8%5D,%5B%22c%22,8,8,1%5D,%5B%22c%22,7,9,0%5D,%5B%22p%22,8.5%5D,%5B%22c%22,8,9,0%5D,%5B%22p%22,9%5D,%5B%22c%22,9,9,1%5D,%5B%22c%22,8,10,0%5D,%5B%22p%22,9.5%5D,%5B%22c%22,9,10,0%5D%5D%5D)

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    in.useDelimiter("\n");
    char[] text = in.next().toCharArray();

    int start = 0;
    int end = 0;
    ArrayList<Integer[]> list = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
    for( ;start<text.length; start++)
    {
        for(end=start; end<=start+1; end++)
        {
            list.add(grow(text, start, end));
        }
    }
    for(Integer[] v: list)
        System.out.println(v[0] +" : "+v[1]);
    findmax(list);
}
static Integer[] grow(char[] text, int start, int end)
{
    while(start>0 && end < text.length && text[start-1]==text[end])
    {
        start--;
        end++;
    }
    return new Integer[]{start, end};
}
static void findmax(ArrayList<Integer[]> list)
{
    int i=0; int j=0;
    for(Integer[] v: list)
    {
        if(v[1]-v[0]>j-i)
        {
            i = v[0];
            j = v[1];
        }
    }
    System.out.println(i+" "+j);
}
```

Comment: Just my two cents on the 'optimized' version above. I'm not sure how much faster this would be since your algorithm is now O(n3) instead of O(n2).

Comment: First code is O(n3) because there are N characters in string, N starting locations and N ending locations. Second is O(n2) or better depending on the input.

Comment: Glad you got it working, sorry for all the crappy advice (I really shouldn't try to answer SO questions on 2 hours of sleep).  I do find it very odd that the second link on google incorrectly describes how java substring works though http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/substring.html

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues:

1: The one I mentioned in the comment above:

```
if(j-i > end-start) {
    start = i;
    end = j;
}
```

2: Let j go all the way to the end of the text:

```
while(j <= text.length())
```

Here's another possibility, now that you've fixed your code, I can give you an alternative more optimized solution if you want it. Finding the biggest palindrome is essentially finding the biggest common word between a string and it's reverse. So start with reversing the string (i.e. text2). Iterate through text (i), then have a sub-iteration that represents the decreasing length (from text.length()-i down to 0. If you find the current word in text2, then you've found a palindrome. You just need to assess whether or not it's the biggest one.

One obvious additional optimization is the sub-iteration for the length doesn't need to go down to zero if you've already found a palindrome.

```
    String text = "absoopoo";       
    String text2 = new StringBuffer(text).reverse().toString();

    int start = 0;
    int end = -1;

    for(int i=0; i<text.length(); i++) {
        for(int length=text.length()-i; length > (end-start); length--) {
            String sub = text.substring(i, i+length);
            if(text2.indexOf(sub) >= 0) {
                start = i;
                end = start+length;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(start + " : " + end+ " => "+text.substring(start, end));
```

Comment: Sorry about that, accidentally edited your answer instead of mine, and took me like 6 tries to get it back to the way it was haha.

Comment: Well that's not cool, I had added also the comments for his implementation and you blew it up :) I'll readd.

Answer (score 0):

Let us know if it is that you need (and if it have good performances) :

```
/** Transmitted max size between to parses */
static int maxSize = 0;

/**
 * Said if the String is a palindrome.
 * 
 * @param s
 *            sentence to parse.
 */
static void singlePalindrome(final String s) {

    System.out.println("singlePalindrome: " + s);
    final char[] word = s.toCharArray();
    final int t = word.length;
    boolean ok = true;
    for (int i = t / 2; i > 0; i--) {

        if (word[i - 1] != word[word.length - i]) {

            ok = false;
            break;
        }

        System.out.println((i - 1) + ":" + word[i - 1] + "\t" + (t - i)
            + ":" + word[t - i]);
    }

    System.out.println("It is " + (true == ok ? "" : "NOT ")
        + "a palindrome.");
}

/**
 * Find all palindromes included anywhere in a sentence, with two search
 * phases from left to right and right to left. Then keep the biggest one *
 * 
 * @param sentence
 *            to parse
 * @param len
 *            minimal size of palindrome(s) to find.
 */
static void palindromeNested(final String sentence, final int len) {
    System.out.println(len + " = minimal size for palindromeNested(..): "
        + sentence);
    int debS = 2;
    String max = null;

    while (debS <= sentence.length()) {

        int i = debS / 2;
        int cpt = 0;
        for (; i <= debS; i++) {
            ++cpt;
            if (sentence.charAt(i) == sentence.charAt(debS - i)) {
                if (cpt >= len) {
                    final String sTmp = (i > debS - i) //
                        ? sentence.substring(debS - i, i + 1) //
                        : sentence.substring(i, debS - i + 1);

                    final int maxTmp = sTmp.length();
                    if (maxTmp > maxSize) {
                        maxSize = maxTmp;
                        max = sTmp;
                        System.out.println(maxTmp + "\t" + max);
                    }

                    // System.out.format("%4d:%-4d %d :: %d %s,\n", i, debS
                    // - i, cpt, maxTmp, sTmp);
                }

                continue;
            }

            break;
        }

        debS++;         
    }

    System.out.println("Result: " + max);

}

/** @param args */
public static void main(final String[] args) {

    singlePalindrome("abccdccba");// "abccddccba" works
    System.out.println("============================");

    // "baabcc dd ccbaabiib" works like "baabcc d ccbaabiib" (odd problem)
    final String words = "baabcc d ccbaabi o iba ab";
    palindromeNested(new StringBuilder(words).reverse().toString(), 3); // 3carsMini
    System.out.println("----------------------------");

    palindromeNested(words, maxSize / 2); // the max found in first
    System.out.println("============================");

}
```

}

Output :

singlePalindrome: abccdccba
3:c 5:c
2:c 6:c
1:b 7:b
0:a 8:a
It is a palindrome.
============================
3 = minimal size for palindromeNested(..): ba abi o ibaabcc d ccbaab
5   ba ab
7   bi o ib
9   abi o iba
Result: abi o iba
----------------------------
4 = minimal size for palindromeNested(..): baabcc d ccbaabi o iba ab
11  abcc d ccba
13  aabcc d ccbaa
15  baabcc d ccbaab
Result: baabcc d ccbaab
============================